# Images on Google Search Results not showing from S3

Tags: seo, amazon-s3

For a django-based website that uses Amazon S3 to handle static images, Google seems to inconsistently show the page's main image in the search results. Sometimes it shows, and sometime's it doesn't.

The image is visually very prominent on the page, and I already added the meta og:image tag.

Does it matter if the url mentioned is a relative url (which would be fetched from the server), or an absolute url (from s3)? I do feel that with a relative url it shows the image more consistently.

How can I tell google to show the s3 image in the search results?